# Azure DevOps Boards with on-premises Git

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-boards

I have wired up CI/CD of my on-premises Git server with Azure DevOps Pipelines using self-hosted agent.

Can I utilize Azure DevOps - Boards for end to end to WorkItem tracking or is it not possible when using on-premises Git?

Comment: Do you want link a work item to your on-premise git commits?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: you can't :/ see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible. Azure DevOps can link to work items only commits from Azure Repos [or from GitHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/github/link-to-from-github) and not from an external on-premise Git server.

(to Jira have [a tool](https://bigbrassband.com) that connect commtis from any git server, but I don't know about a tool for Azure DevOps).